# Why is the @Transactional annotation being ignored in this method?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, rollback

I encountered this issue when attempting to apply the @Transactional annotation to a method (methodC()) within the same class (MyService). Despite using the annotation, the transaction does not seem to be created as expected.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private Service1 service1;

  @Autowired
  private Service2 service2;


  @Override
  public void methodA() {
    methodB();
  }

  private void methodB() {
    try{  
      methodC();
    }catch(MyException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  @Transactional
  public void methodC() throws MyException, Exception{
    try{
      service1.someDeleteAndInserts();
      service2.someDeleteAndInserts();
    }catch(MyException e){
      throw e;
    }catch(Exception e){
      throw e;
    }
    
  }
}
```

As I have it now, it creates a transaction for each method individually. I want it to make only one transaction for all the methods called within that method.

```
@Transactional
  public void methodC() throws MyException, Exception{
    try{
      service1.someDeleteAndInserts();
      service2.someDeleteAndInserts();
    }catch(MyException e){
      throw e;
    }catch(Exception e){
      throw e;
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: The first rule about `@Transactional` - it doesnt get triggered when called from within a class and should always be called from outside (if you read about proxy pattern reasons become obvious, the proxy can't see calls made from within the object it wraps)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method annotated `@Transactional` within the same service. You can only call it from outside the service otherwise no transaction will be created. Every spring service is a proxy and the transactions (AOP) are created on the proxy so as soon as you enter any method you are no longer in the proxy so no AOP (no transactions).

Note: you can however put `@Transactional` on `methodA()` to create a transaction but the transaction will start as soon as you call it, not when it reaches `methodC`, also any transaction exception will be propagated to where you called `methodA()` not `methodC()`.

For example if you have:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

    @Transactional
    public void method1() { ... }

    public void method2() {
        method1();
    }
}

@Service
public class Service2 {

    @Autowired
    private Service1 service1;

    public void method1() {
        service1.method1();
    }

    public void method2() {
        service1.method2();
    }
}
```

- Calling `service1.method2()` will **NOT** create a transaction.
- Calling `service1.method1()` will create one.
- Calling `service2.method2()` will **NOT** create a transaction.
- Calling `service2.method1()` will create one.

Because of the way Spring handles Proxies and AOP.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers and comments have pointed out, you must call this across proxy boundaries to make this work.  The same thing applies to other annotations like `@Cacheable`.

There is a little trick that you can do to make this work, and that's autowiring an instance of the Service into itself and call the method on the injected version.

```
 @Service
 // 1. Set the proxy mode to TARGET_CLASS
 @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 public class MyService {

   // 2. Autowire an instance of the service into itself
   @Autowired
   private MyService self;

   private void methodB() {
     try{
       // 3. Call methodC through your injected version
       self.methodC();
     }catch(MyException e){
       System.out.println(e);
     }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e);
     }
   }
 }
```

Now, when you call methodC using the injected service, it will participate in the transaction.

Comment: Looks a bit hackish but it gets the job done :)