# How to invoke a method, annotated by @Transactional annotation from non-transactional method correct way in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is sample code of Spring Boot with @Transactional annotation. My Server is WildFly. I am using JTA transaction which is provided by WildFly module. The database connection of my application and 3rd party service is acquired by JNDI, configured in WildFly standalone configuration file.

```
@Service
public class MyUpdateService {
    public void update(MyModel myModel){

       MyEntity updatedEntity = updateToDB(myModel);

       myThirdPartyService.update(100);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateToDB(MyModel myModel) {

       MyEntity currentEntity = myRepository.fetchById(myModel.getId());

       currentEntity.setName(myModel.getName());

       return currentEntity;
    }
}
```

When I look at the table, the table is not updated by new name, even thought it is wrapped by @Transactional annotation.

My Question, how do I perform update operation in separate method of the same class?

Comment: Spring creates a proxy and wraps the service to intercept calls of a transactional method, but it cannot be intercepted if you call the method from within the class.

Comment: Easiest answer is: put the transactional stuff in a separate class.

Comment: you can look at my detailed answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593865/why-is-the-transactional-annotation-being-ignored-in-this-method/77594140#77594140